Eclipse IDE 2024-03 crashes under Ubuntu, causing hr_err_pid.log
I have two classes, "PeerMessage" and "PeerMessageOps" (this is just an example). PeerMessageOps contains constant values that PeerMessage class accesses to. But I don't know why, every time I do the "PeerMessageOps.thing" from PeerMessage class, Eclipse stops running and exits leaving an hr_err_pid.log archive in personal folder (I don't understand anything in there). This started happening after I incorporated new source archives to an already existing project. This also happen with any of the previous archives that I was already using. If i don't access to one class from another this problem doesn't happen and everything runs normally.
hr_err_pid.log (screenshot):
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007884fd3b61f8, pid=3363, tid=3364
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (17.0.9+9) (build 17.0.9+9)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (17.0.9+9, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37+0xdb61f8]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/mpatari/core.3363)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10 -Doomph.update.url=https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-oomph/oomph/master/setups/ --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla /home/mpatari/eclipse/jee-2023-092/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.500.v20230717-2134.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash /home/mpatari/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.29.0.20230907-1200/splash.bmp -launcher /home/mpatari/eclipse/jee-2023-092/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /home/mpatari/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.2.700.v20221108-1024/eclipse_11801.so -startup /home/mpatari/eclipse/jee-2023-092/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.500.v20230717-2134.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 2 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -vm /home/mpatari/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_17.0.9.v20231028-0858/jre/bin/java -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true -Dsun.java.command=Eclipse -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10 -Doomph.update.url=https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-oomph/oomph/master/setups/ --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla -jar /home/mpatari/eclipse/jee-2023-092/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.500.v20230717-2134.jar

Host: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-12100, 8 cores, 7G, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Time: Thu Apr 18 12:46:35 2024 IST elapsed time: 678.075570 seconds (0d 0h 11m 18s)

I've tried reinstalling Eclipse and create a new workspace to import previous project and problem is still there. I'm running Eclipse from Ubuntu and project is in Java. I also checked Eclipse is updated to the last version. Would be very thankful for a response.

Even if you don't understand anything in hr_err_pid.log, someone else might. Please share details of what is in it.

It might be this. Please try whether it is fixed in the first milestone of the upcoming release: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2024-06/m1

@howlger it worked!! By installing the version you linked now everything works just fine. Thank you so much.

This is a workaround:
cd eclipse
export GDK_BACKEND=x11;
./eclipse 

Wayland is a buggy X11 replacement. Using GDK_BACKEND=x11 forces a compatibility-mode. After an update of ubuntu you could try to remove that GDK_BACKEND to check if eclipse works normal again.
If you are using Ubuntu and like to have a starter icon in the menu, save this file as ~/.local/share/applications/Eclipse.desktop according to your eclipse installation (replace xxx with your username accordingly):
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Java IDE
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;
Exec= env GDK_BACKEND=x11 /home/xxx/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/home/xxx/eclipse/icon.xpm
Name[en_US]=Eclipse

Now, you should be able to start Eclipse using the "Dash" and Pin it to the sidebar.

I had an existing desktop file under a slightly different name but in the same directory. I modified that one and it seems to work.

Already fixed the issue but appreciate the response :)

Using this workaround solved the problem. Wayland stills crash eclipse and kill ubuntu 24 session, for me

This is a known issue that has already been fixed for the upcoming Eclipse IDE version 2024-06 (4.32) which will be released on June 12, 2024.
See Eclipse SWT issue #381 - Eclipse crashes with # C [libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37+0xbc8316]
As a workaround for some, but not all cases, you can use the first (or as soon as available, a newer) milestone of the upcoming release until the Eclipse IDE 2024-06 (4.32) is released.
If you do not want to use a milestone build or if the workaround does not work for you, the following answers might help:

Peter Rader's answer on how to use X11 instead of Wayland
Jan Nielsen's answer on how to disable WebKit's DMA buffer renderer (which should not be needed when using a milestone build or an upcoming release)


No, it still doesn't work. Even when using Eclipse with Wayland, there are certain actions performed within the IDE that terminate the user session and close everything in Ubuntu 24.

@Max The question was about Eclipse IDE 2024-03 and Ubuntu 22, not Ubuntu 24. If you still use Eclipse IDE 2024-03, please upgrade. Please ask a separate question including the hr_err_pid.log (does it also contain SIGSEGV and C  [libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37+0xdb61f8]?) and information about the exact versions of Eclipse, Wayland and GTK you use. Also be aware that there are similar looking issues with NVIDIA graphics card drivers. So, please also tell whether you are using an NVIDIA GPU with an NVIDIA driver.

Thank you for your answer, @howlger. Yes, I've been using the 06/2024 version of Eclipse for some time now. I've just posted a question about this problem elsewhere, so I won't clutter this discussion further with an unnecessary topic. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524912/ubuntu-24-eclipse-wayland-amd-gpu-killing-session

yes, sorry about that.
