Eclipse crahing each time when i try to import built in libraries or enter words on Version: 2024-06 (4.32.0)
I tried many ways ,but i can't solve it.I also tried by installing other version and it also not working.Then i tryed other ubuntu version like 22 version it worked but not work with 24.04 LTS.
log file:
!SESSION 2024-06-29 17:01:28.596 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.32.0.20240606-1231
java.version=21.0.3
java.vendor=Ubuntu
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
!ENTRY ch.qos.logback.classic 1 0 2024-06-29 17:01:34.424
!MESSAGE Activated before the state location was initialized. Retry after the state location is initialized.
!ENTRY ch.qos.logback.classic 1 0 2024-06-29 17:01:52.327
!MESSAGE Logback config file: /home/sat/Documents/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback/logback.2.6.1.20240411-1122.xml
I tried bellow artice
1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78355080/eclipse-ide-2024-03-crashes-under-ubuntu-causing-hr-err-pid-log
2.Tried with other jdk and jvm version

Probably this
